# MySQL Replication: Seconds Behind Master keep growing

Tags: mysql, replication

We have set up a new slave server for our production database. Since than the Seconds_Behind_Master keep growing slowly.

This is the slave output:

> ```
>            Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
>               Master_Host: notimportant
>               Master_User: repl
>               Master_Port: 3306
>             Connect_Retry: 60
>           Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003790
>       Read_Master_Log_Pos: 42585179
>            Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.002798
>             Relay_Log_Pos: 32374374
>     Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.003492
>          Slave_IO_Running: Yes
>         Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
>           Replicate_Do_DB: 
>       Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
>        Replicate_Do_Table: 
>    Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
>   Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:  
>                Last_Errno: 0
>                Last_Error: 
>              Skip_Counter: 0
>       Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 32374215
>           Relay_Log_Space: 31350956440
>           Until_Condition: None
>            Until_Log_File: 
>             Until_Log_Pos: 0
>        Master_SSL_Allowed: No
>        Master_SSL_CA_File: 
>        Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
>           Master_SSL_Cert: 
>         Master_SSL_Cipher: 
>            Master_SSL_Key: 
>     Seconds_Behind_Master: 1448477
>             Last_IO_Errno: 0
>             Last_IO_Error: 
>            Last_SQL_Errno: 0
>          Master_Server_Id: 6524
>               Master_UUID: 
>          Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
>                 SQL_Delay: 0
>       SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
>   Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
>        Master_Retry_Count: 86400
>               Master_Bind: 
>   Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
>  Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
>            Master_SSL_Crl: 
>        Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
>        Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
>         Executed_Gtid_Set: 
>             Auto_Position: 0
> ```

Show processlist on SLAVE:

```
|    1 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 2143813 | Waiting for master to send event | NULL             |
|    2 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 1448477 | Reading event from the relay log | NULL             |
| 1628 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |       0 | init                             | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
```

On MASTER side:

```
|  7947837 | repl       | host-vm:59420     | NULL          | Binlog Dump | 2143817 | Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated | NULL             |
```

On MASTER the show slave hosts:

```
+-----------+------+------+-----------+
| Server_id | Host | Port | Master_id |
+-----------+------+------+-----------+
|      3410 |      | 3410 |      6524 |
| 347643210 |      | 3306 |      6524 |
+-----------+------+------+-----------+
```

Does anyone has an idea what's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Eh?  "host-vm:59420" looks nothing like what is in the Slave Status.  Is replication mis-configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the following to `my.cnf`:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Our server was slow in I/O and the row above reduced the disk usage.

It is not recommended for bank databases, but recommended to all others.

Phrased differently:  `=1` flushes at then end of each transaction, thereby making it ACID-compliant.  `=2` flushes to disk every second, thereby being much less I/O-intensive.

Comment: MySQL docs recommend: *"**For durability and consistency in a replication setup that uses InnoDB with transactions**:

    If binary logging is enabled, set `sync_binlog=1`.

    **Always set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1`.**
"*

Comment: Also please try to explain why this change is a solution to the issue. What does it do exactly and how it is related to the issue in the question.